# highcharts legend marker and series marker with different size

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to plot only markers on the Scatter Chart. The problem is whatever marker size I've specified for series marker is also applied for the legend marker. How to have different marker size for Legend and Series.
Please refer to this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/balraj8/yxajypx0/9/).

In Fiddle the difference in marker size not clearly visible, so here is the screenshot from the browser.

[image]

```
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        animation: false,
        marker: {
            radius: 5,
            //fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: null,
            radius:22,
            symbol : 'square',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                }
            }
        },

        /*tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
        }*/
    }
},
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting symbolHeight on your legend?

```
legend: {
    enabled:true,
    symbolHeight: 10
},
```

Comment: @morganfree I've tried what you've suggested. In the fiddle it is working whereas in the browser it is not showing the same result as fiddle. If you notice when we increase radius of Series Marker, Legend Marker is also changing its size. _Is there any other way to do it?_

Comment: I checked this in chrome 54/Highcharts 5.0.7 and it works exactly as in the fiddle. What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm using it inside my application, may be some CSS might be effecting it. I'll try to figure it out.